# pass dropdown selected values(list) as a parameter via Ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, jquery, drop-down-menu

He all,

i have a dropdown combo box , i need to send the selected value as a list to my controller.

i have tried something like this.

dropdown :

```
  <g:select name="clientId" id="clientId"  multiple = "yes" size = "4" from="${com.springpeople.steer.partymodel.roles.ClientRole.list()}" class = "filter_combo" optionKey="id" />
```

**method to call on changing** :

```
 $("#clientId").change(function(){
 var clientId = $("#clientId").val(); // it gives clientId  = 1,2,3
 var department = document.getElementById("departmentId");
 department.options.length=0;
 fillDepartment(clientId,"filter_department","${createLink(controller:'report', action:'fillDepartments')}")
              }
```

**fillDepartmentInFilter ajax call method:**

```
function fillDepartment(clientId,department_div_id,fillDepartmentUrl,selectedDepartmentIds){
    $.ajax({
        url:fillDepartmentUrl,
        data: ({clientId :clientId,departmentId:selectedDepartmentIds}),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+department_div_id).html("");
            $("#"+department_div_id).attr("disabled", true);
            $("#"+department_div_id).attr("color")
            $("#"+department_div_id).html(data);
         }
    });
}
```

i want to get the clientId values as a list in controller.. how can i do it.. right now when i am trying to print the value of parameters it gives me value like this

> fillDepartments :: parameters = [clientId[]:[3, 13, 9], action:fillDepartments, controller:report]
>   fillDepartments :: clientid = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all of selected indexes and then fetch them as a string to your AJAX. In your server-side script code split them with the splitter that you defined like ',' at below:

```
var cmb = document.getElementById('clientID');
var selItems = "";
for(i=0;i<cmb.options.length;i+=1){
  if(cmb.options[i].selected){
    selItems = selItems + cmb.options[i].value + ",";
  }
}
// Remove the last splitter
selItems = selItems.substr(0,selItems.length-1);
```

Then pass the `selItems` to your `data` parameter in jQuery's AJAX.

Hope my code would be correct, I didn't tested it.